# Am trying to submit the form in Django but it's not submitting. I would like to kno where l did a mistake

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I got a problem, when l try to submit the form it just **reflesh** the page and the form it's not submitted. I don't know why.

Below l have two instances, a form view which l would like to use and submit data  and it's in  *A* as below. **But not working**

**Form view A**

```
def actionreview(request, cid):
    url= request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= ActionReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            gamereview=ActionGameReview()
            review = request.POST.get('review')
            rating = request.POST.get('rating')
            gamereview.review = review
            gamereview.rating = rating
            gamereview.game_name_id=cid
            current_user = request.user 
            gamereview.user_id=current_user.id
            gamereview.save()
        #if ActionGameReview.objects.filter(game_name_id=id, user_id=user_id).exists():
            #return HttpResponse("review already submitted")
        #else:
            #gamereview.save()
        return redirect(url)
    return redirect("/")
```

Here l have the *form view B*. This one works but seems not to be a good form because am trying to add validation for form but not recognised.

**Form view B**

```
def actionreview(request, cid):
    url= request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reviewform= ActionReviewForm()
        gamereview = ActionGameReview()
        review = request.POST.get('review')
        rating = request.POST.get('rating')
        gamereview.review = review
        gamereview.rating = rating
        gamereview.game_name_id=cid
        current_user = request.user 
        gamereview.user_id=current_user.id
        gamereview.save()
        #if ActionGameReview.objects.filter(game_name_id=id, user_id=user_id).exists():
            #return HttpResponse("review already submitted")
        #else:
            #gamereview.save()
        return redirect(url)
    return redirect("/")
```

Below it's my *forms.py* as it looks like.

```
from Action.models import ActionGameReview

class ActionReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    review=forms.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ActionGameReview
        fields = [ 'review', 'rating']
```

Here it's the *URL* that operates on the both form views

```
path('actionreview/<int:cid>', views.actionreview, name='actionreview'),
```

Here it the *html* for the form which submits the form.

```
    <form action="{% url 'actionreview' description.id %}" method="POST" id="commentForm" class="commentForm">
      {% csrf_token %}
```

**Some edit**
Someone asked me the codes for the model and it's below:

**Model**

```
RATING=[
    (1,"★"),
    (2,"★★"),
    (3,"★★★"),
    (4,"★★★★"),
    (5,"★★★★★"),
]


class ActionGameReview(models.Model):
    game_name =models.ForeignKey(ActionGame, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    user =models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review =models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=RATING)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.game_name.game_name
    class Meta:
        ordering=['-created_at']
        get_latest_by= str('created_at')
```

Any assistance is appreciated and guidance, thanks

In *form view A* it doesn't submit the form

In *form view B* it submits but l can't use form validations

Comment: What is the error or the reason why version A is not working? There has to be a ValidationError. What does it say?

Comment: It returns nothing like an error, just what l found is that when l submit the form, it nor save the form but it directs me to `return redirect ("/")`  yet l expected to save the form and return me to The exact page i.e  `return redirect (url)`

Comment: Can you please also share the code of your model called `ActionGameReview`? Append it to your question via the edit function.

Comment: Okay am going to add it

Comment: Let me try on it and l will alert you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I sense multiple reasons for validation failure here. But first see this general setup that maybe leads you to your troubles yourself.

You should log, or simply print out the reason why the form is not saving. So for debugging purposes do something like this:

```py
def actionreview(request, cid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActionReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            e = form.errors
            print(f"Is not valid because {e}")
  
    else:
        form = ActionReviewForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Now: After checking `is_valid()` you should not use `request.POST.get('review')` anymore. You want to refer to it via `form.cleaned_data.get('review')`. The difference being that the latter is "cleaned" while the first is still the raw user input. Read more about `cleaned_data` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data).

Also read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) about `request.POST`

This already leads to the mistake in your code. Your `rating` wants to have an integer, since the model is a `models.IntegerField`. I am quite sure, that the following is true when the user selects the second rating:

```py
print(request.POST.get('rating'))
>> '(2,"★★")'
print(form.cleaned_data.get('review'))
>> 2
```

So what happens for you is the following flow: Your input is technically correct. Your `form.is_valid()` evaluates to `True` because you chose the valid option for rating. But then you did not try to store the `2` to the database, but instead you are trying to store `'(2,"★★")'` to the database.

Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) how django deals with your `RATING`